# Position absolute issue

Tags: html, css

When I trying to place elements as static html text everything works, but when I trying to place elements in runtime (arrays of data from server) I have issue positioning as `absolute`. Simplest example to reproduce

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Positioning</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        body { font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 14px }
        div { border: 1px solid black }
        .div5 { float: left; width: 300px; height: 300px; }
        .div6 { width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; background-color: #F5D8C1 }
        .div9 { width: 20px; height: 20px; position: absolute; bottom: 20px; left: 20px; background-color: #D8F5C1 }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        function setDivValue($divId, $value)
        {
            var divL = document.getElementById($divId);
            if (divL)
                divL.innerHTML = $value;
        }

        var rtext = "<h1>Position absolute test</h1>";
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            rtext +=    "<div class='div5' id='" + i + "'>" +
                            "<div class='div6'>div6</div>" +
                            "<div class='div9'>div9</div>" +
                        "</div>";
        }
        setDivValue("content", rtext);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

it placing div6 and div9 not by parent element div5, but positioning to window in both FF 20 and IE 8 (so that isn't browser related bug it seems).

Is it possible to solve it? I need to place for example pictures to div6 and put text to div9 right over top left corner of picture (inside).

Comment: IF you create a JsFiddle file it will become easy to help you.

Comment: JsFiddle forcing me to split everything (html, css, js) and when I do this nothing works at all.

Comment: Let it be like that. Atleast we can see the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add these CSS:

```
#content{position:relative;}
```

Comment: Now all 10 elements of type div6 and div9 positioned at the top of page, not inside every 10 div5 as should be by doc on position `absolute` - positioning to parent element.

Comment: Idea with `position:relative;` was good, except it should be set to `div5` (parent element for both `div6` and `div9`). I will set as answer and you can change your post :)